# Form Does Not Submit in Opera Mini Using Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, opera-mini

I'm developing a mobile site. I'm using jquery mobile. The forms on the site to do not submit when I'm using the site in Opera Mini. When I click on "Submit" the page just refreshes and nothing happens.

I tried creating a basic form, (not wrapped in Jquery mobile), and the form submitted without any problems. Which leads me to believe that the issue is with jQuery Mobile. I already have "data-ajax = 'false'" in my form, but it still won't submit.

Comment: please dont post links to live sites, just include your code instead.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the issue was because I had another open form element (I had forgotten to comment it out). This caused the issue. Thanks for all who took a look at this.